# My external python modules are not showing up because python isn't in Path, how do I relocate them?

Tags: python, path, python-import, importerror, python-module

I am fairly new to python, I would like advice on how to move python into Path. Currently, when I run pip install keyboard, the "Requirement already satisfied" shows up. I am using Visual Studio Code. But later, when I attempt to import the keyboard module, the error says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'. I am stuck, and would like some help. Thank you in advance.

I have tried editing the enviroment variables and making the python "\scripts" and "\python311" a Path, but it did not work. I have tried googling solutions and tried all of them I came across. I could not get it to work.

Comment: Most likely you have different Python versions installed and your `pip` uses different one than VSC runs your Python code with. You can either clean up your Path or select a different Python interpreter in VSCode to make sure they use the same version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Requirement already satisfied" than this package is at least available in that  Python environment. If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can select your python environment as follows:
Hit cntrl + shift + P, than in the task bar type in: 'Python: Select Interpreter'
Than choose the python version on which you installed 'keyboard'.

Note that it would be good practice to create virtual environments. In here you can download all the packages you need and make it specific for a certain project. You could do this using anaconda or directly with python:

```
python -m venv ./.venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
```

This will create a new environment, saved in current directory (you should go to your project folder before this). The second line is to activate it.
or

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

This will save and activate a conda environment.
After you have activated your environment install keyboard with conda or pip:

```
pip install keyboard
conda install keyboard
```

If you do above in a terminal in Visual studio code than you should have the python environment activated and have keyboard installed